# Keep Service Running with Upstart

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, service, upstart

I am trying to use upstart to keep a service running: rabbitmq-server.

I have written an upstart configuration file in /etc/init/rabbitmq.conf

```
  1
  2 start on runlevel [2345]
  3 stop on runlevel [016]
  4
  5 respawn
  6 exec /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
```

The problem is that this script thinks that rabbitmq-server has crashed right after it runs and it continues to try and restart it until upstart determines it has restarted too many times and ultimatly exits:

```
Aug 29 19:01:47 WORKER1 kernel: [ 1334.301258] init: rabbitmq main process ended, respawning
Aug 29 19:01:48 WORKER1 kernel: [ 1334.740770] init: rabbitmq main process ended, respawning
Aug 29 19:01:48 WORKER1 kernel: [ 1335.227660] init: rabbitmq main process ended, respawning
Aug 29 19:01:49 WORKER1 kernel: [ 1335.721948] init: rabbitmq respawning too fast, stopped
```

How can I write an upstart script to keep a service running?

Comment: Fix whatever is causing it to crash.

Comment: It's not crashing I just want to have a safeguard in case it does